# Salesforce Streaming API: Recconnect to Cometd after session expires

Tags: javascript, salesforce, cometd

What is the best way to restart a cometd session after the old one has expired? Specifically when using the CometD Javascript Library and Salesforce Streaming API.

Currently I'm trying to write a series of Web Pages that use the Salesforce Streaming API,which runs using Cometd, to automatically update data on the page. This is working fine, but I'm now trying to deal with what to do after the session expires.

Currently I'm testing in a very small time frame, specifically 20 seconds. I call the code below twice. First when the page loads and again after 20 seconds.

```
$.cometd.clearListeners();
$.cometd.init({
                url:window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/cometd/28.0/',
                requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'}
            });
            [Initialize Subscriptions]
```

This works okay, but not without some problems that I'd like to avoid.

It looks like if I receive a call through my subscriptions before the code above runs the 2nd time, my subscriptions handlers fire twice on the next call it catches. I've tried replacing $.cometd.init with $.cometd.handshake, but this never seemed to work unless my subscriptions received a call before the code above was called a 2nd time. I also tried calling  $.cometd.disconnect, but this seemed to block any calls from reaching my subscriptions after I call that function, even if I run it synchronously.

Am I doing it right and the 20 second interval is messing things up or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: using the solution detailed in the accepted answer, is your clearListeners() any longer necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering from the [CometD](http://cometd.org) point of view.

The best way to restart a CometD session after the old one expired is to do nothing.

CometD has an automatic reconnect feature so if the network connection drops and the session expires, CometD will automatically retry until it succeeds to connect again with the server, with a backoff interval between attempts.

In order to guarantee that your subscriptions are restored on re-handshake, you just need to follow [the guidelines](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript_subscribe_vs_listen), in particular perform your subscriptions from a `/meta/handshake` successful listener.

If you want to test your JavaScript code behaviour in case of a disconnection, you just need to create the disconnection, and not calling `cometd.init()` twice.
You can kill the server, unplug the network cable, undeploy the webapp, etc.

If you explicitly disconnect the client, then you have to re-handshake manually:

```js
cometd.init(...);
...

// Disconnect
cometd.disconnect();
// Wait a while, then re-handshake
cometd.handshake();
```

Note that you **must** "wait a while" because `cometd.disconnect()` is asynchronous.
Alternatively, you can do:

```js
cometd.init(...);
...

// Disconnect and re-handshake when fully disconnected
cometd.addListener('/meta/disconnect', function(message) 
{ 
    cometd.handshake(); 
});
cometd.disconnect();

// Another solution, using setTimeout()
cometd.disconnect();
window.setTimeout(function() 
{ 
    cometd.handshake(); 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wasn't using listeners anywhere, which was my main problem. So besides needing to do a handshake on 'meta/disconnect' listener, I also need to add a listener for '/meta/handshake' to start my subscriptions. Doing that seems to work.

Comment: I am getting Error 401 when i m trying to do the Handshake. I have a BaseURL , an access token which i added to header field of Request. Please let me know what wrong i m doing.

Comment: HTTP error 401 means you are trying to access a page that needs credentials. You are probably trying to access the wrong page, or with the wrong credentials.